# Why is my IIS site missing style when the AppPool identity is one service account but displays properly when using another?

Tags: css, iis

Using Server 2019 with IIS.
I have an AppPool that has an identity of ServiceAccountA.  When I open the website, the page appears as if there is no styling.  When I change the identity to use ServiceAccountB, the webpage looks correct.  How can I figure out what permissions are missing on ServiceAccountA?
I made sure both accounts are in the IIS_USRS group.

Comment: If the styling cannot be loaded, there will usually be an error message in the console. You can solve the problem according to the error message, and thus obtain the difference in permissions between the two accounts.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  However, I am fairly new to IIS (coming from an Oracle background), and I am struggling to find any decent logging.  I checked C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles but the verbosity doesn't appear to be high enough.  Is there any way in IIS to increase the verbosity to see more logs in the log files?

Comment: There should be no related error messages in the iis log, you can check the page, console or Event Viewer.